# The view canvas.views.pdfDirectory didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python

Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:

The view canvas.views.pdfDirectory didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 129

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import cm, mm, inch, pica

def pdfDirectory(imageDirectory, outputPDFName = 'ima.pdf'):
    dirim = str(imageDirectory)
    output = str(outputPDFName)
    width, height = letter
    height, width = letter
    c = canvas.Canvas(output, pagesize=letter)
    # try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirim):
        for name in files:
            lname = name.lower()
            if lname.endswith(".JPG") or lname.endswith(".gif") or      lname.endswith(".png"):
                filepath = os.path.join('/home/deepak/Downloads', 'image')
                c.drawImage('/home/deepak/Downloads/imag.pdf', inch, inch * 1)
                c.showPage()
                c.save()
                return output
    #   print "PDF of Image directory created"
    # except:
    #  print "Failed creating PDF"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code never enters the if statement inside your for loop the function will return `None` which is not a `HttpResponse` object. In your if statement you are returning a string, which is also not a `HttpResponse` object. Just wrap it in a `HttpResponse` object:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirim):
    for name in files:
        lname = name.lower()
        if lname.endswith(".JPG") or lname.endswith(".gif") or lname.endswith(".png"):
            filepath = os.path.join('/home/deepak/Downloads', 'image')
            c.drawImage('/home/deepak/Downloads/imag.pdf', inch, inch * 1)
            c.showPage()
            c.save()                    
            return HttpResponse(output)
return HttpResponse("Failed creating PDF")
```

Comment: Thanks but now why it is not creating .pdf  please help me out.

Comment: now this code is working but failed to create pdf file so guide me how to create the pdf

Comment: If you have problems with PDF creation that should be a separate question.

Comment: sir I posted that question also code is same so only asked your help.